# SUM contiguous values in column

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

Is it possible to `SUM` groups of contiguous values in a column without manually grouping them one by one the way I have in this picture?

[image]

[sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nxQiHPNjqptgM2iSSOcM80y0ER-8G8YU_JEW-VXOByo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE({"♥"&MMULT(
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 ROW(A2:A), )))="", "♦", A2:A)), "♦")), " ")*1, ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 ROW(A2:A), )))="", "♦", A2:A)), "♦")), " ")*1)))^0),IF(
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A2:A<>"", 
 ROW(A2:A), )))="", "♦", A2:A)), "♦")), " ")<>"", "♥♠", )}), "♥")), "♠", ))
```

[image: 0]